# how to connect two web services through esb?

Tags: java, web-services, esb, mule-studio

I have been learning how to create web services but i can't find any good documentations or tutorials that can help understand how to make them communicate through an esb. I have to use mulesoft anypoint studio. I would like to know how to do that, at least an exemple that would explain it clearly and with details.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What sort of research have you done? What have you tried already? A quick look seems to show a wealth of content on the Mulesoft forums, which may be a better place for a very general high-level question like this.

Comment: Try Mulesoft’s training site https://training.mulesoft.com/category/mulesoftu. This topic is too broad for a SO question